# Automated Driver Checking

Tags: wds

I was wondering is there any possible way to automatically check to see whether drivers have installed correctly or not through WDS.  I would automate the process to the oobe set-up however the only way i know how to check the driver installation log is through device manager or through shift+f10 and getting the log file but is there any way to check it without user input?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the log files without user input (with a script) and/or directly query the clients to return what hardware and drivers are installed on the system via WMI (also something that can be scripted).

Comment: Hmm if I were to go via the first script route how would I go about setting that up? I am not very familiar with Scripts.

Comment: @Atlas Well, you'd write a script to either parse the log for your install return codes or to query the machine for installed hardware and associated drivers via WMI... I mean, if you're asking how to learn to script, that's a whole different matter, but if you hit up Google, you should be able to find plenty of sites that will show you how to [blah] with Powershell.  I suggest that.